# How to install a certbot dns plugin that is not available in the SnapStore using pip (certbot-dns-hetzner)

Tags: pip, certbot, certbot-dns-plugin

Before I did use `certbot-auto` what is not supportet in my current system anymore:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
curl https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto > certbot-auto
chmod 755 certbot-auto
./certbot-auto
```

results in the following error message

```
Skipping bootstrap because certbot-auto is deprecated on this system.
Your system is not supported by certbot-auto anymore.
Certbot cannot be installed.
Please visit https://certbot.eff.org/ to check for other alternatives.
```

Now I'll have to install certbot using `snap install --classic certbot` what results in a completely other file structure so that my old installation with these commands does not work any longer (here installing the Hetzner DNS plugin).

```
cd /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin
./pip2.7 install certbot-dns-hetzner
```

So how to install the plugins now? Where to find the certbot folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the snap installation of certbot and a dns plugin this way (I am working as root in Ubuntu 18.04  so please prepend `sudo` if you're not root).

### Don't be deceived

At least on Ubuntu I relly got deceived by `certbot plugins`, that did not show the plugin even though it is perfectly working.

Install pip, certbot (with snap) and then simply do the pip installation of the plugin.

```
apt install python3-pip
snap install --classic certbot
python3 -m pip install certbot-dns-hetzner
certbot plugins
```

Now `certbot plugins` does not list your installed plugin but again, don't get fooled, it will work (at least it did work for me).

If you are running into problems, have a look into the letsencrypt.log (normally */var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log*) and find the paths let's encrypt searches for plugins (folder `dist-packages`). You should use the same python version, let's encrypt uses when installing your plugin.

### The wrong way

After trying the right way above (not knowing that certbot already could find and use the dns plugin), I went on trying this. I thought this is the right way and got deceived by `certbot plugin` because the plugin showed up but was not found while running a certbot request.
So this is just for the ones being interested in failures ;-)

Install certbot and check installed plugins:

```
snap install --classic certbot
certbot plugins
```

Install the desired dns plugin into your certbot (here Hetzner DNS) installation and check if installation succeeded:

```
cd /snap/certbot/current/usr/bin
./python3 -m pip install certbot-dns-hetzner
certbot plugins
```

**Note:**
Some plugins are already prepared to be installed by snap, what is the easiest way of installation. Search the [SnapStore](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=certbot-dns) to find out if your desired plugin is already available in a snap version (like certbot-dns-cloudxns, certbot-dns-madeeasy, certbot-dns-dnssimple, ...).

```
snap install certbot-dns-cloudxns
```

Answer (score 2):

The Plugins are available via snap, just use the find command to discover them

```
# snap find certbot
Name                      Version  Publisher        Notes    Summary
certbot                   1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     classic  Automatically configure HTTPS using Let's Encrypt
certbot-dns-cloudxns      1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        CloudXNS DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-cloudflare    1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        Cloudflare DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-dnsmadeeasy   1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        DNS Made Easy DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-dnsimple      1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        DNSimple DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-digitalocean  1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        DigitalOcean DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-nsone         1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        NS1 DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-sakuracloud   1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        Sakura Cloud DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-rfc2136       1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        RFC 2136 DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-ovh           1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        OVH DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-luadns        1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        LuaDNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-linode        1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        Linode DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-route53       1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        Route53 DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-gehirn        1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        Gehirn Infrastructure Service DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-google        1.20.0   certbot-eff✓     -        Google Cloud DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-hetzner       1.0.5    bigmichi1        -        Hetzner DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-porkbun       v0.2.1   infinityofspace  -        Porkbun DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-duckdns       v0.6.1   infinityofspace  -        DuckDNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-inwx          2.1.3    oggy             -        INWX DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
certbot-dns-aliyun        0.38.1   tengattack       -        Aliyun DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot
passprox                  2.3.2    nsg              -        HAProxy with a bundled Certbot (Let's Encrypt support)
dnsrobocert               3.13.0   adferrand        -        Deploy and orchestrate DNS-challenged Let's Encrypt TLS certificates
tomcat-with-ssl           0.1      bsuttton         -        Apache Tomcat with SSL activated and managed by Certbot.
```

Then install with `snap install certbot-dns-hetzner`

Answer (score 0):

you can try the snap published here: https://snapcraft.io/certbot-dns-hetzner

Answer (score 0):

I installed a DNS plugin `pip install certbot-dns-ionos` but `certbot plugins` would not display it.

So I followed this article and it fixed my issue: https://www.rushworth.us/lisa/?p=8887

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/certbot_dns_ionos /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/certbot-2.7.1.dist-info /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```